# How can I add pdf viewer in my app using asset folder?

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I am going to add a pdf file in my app and to load it from asset folder using asset folder but when I Add PDFView library it show my an error like nothing was added.

I have added the following dependency in build.gradle file:
`implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'`

and in my xml file:

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and jetpack.io library is added to settings.gradle file

```
lll
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the JitPack repository to your gradle

Comment: @javdromero I have added the repository into settings.gradle file already.

Comment: @WiqarAli have you tried to replace ```3.2.0-beta.1``` version with ```2.8.2``` ?

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani yes I have also tried that